# How to prevent model from peeling off of resin printer buildplate during print?

Tags: sla, resin

Recently I have started using a fairly large LCD resin printer. (Yidimu Falcon Pro)
It has a fairly large 260x160mm perforated and coated steel build plate and a decent dual rail Z axis with a ballscrew. It has a 10" LCD. It prints ChiTuBox files from a USB stick.

I have been having a mostly successful print, at good quality, but the bed adhesion keeps haunting me. The best print on this machine had parts curling up from the build plate, however most of the print succeeded.

- Two times I have had a very well adhering raft, however delamination occured directly after the raft.
- Usually the left side lifts from the bed while the model stays on the build plate.

I have tried:

Changing resin (tried Druckwerk Pro D Black and Anycubic Black)

- Decreasing lift speed
- Increasing lift distance
- Increasing bottom layer exposure time (from 60 to 180, as suggested by Druckwerck supplier)
- Increasing bottom layer count to 9
- Using a large raft
- Using a very large raft
- Using a very small raft
- Leveling build plate without vat in place, using paper
- Leveling build plate while keeping vat in place

What would be a good next troubleshooting step?

[image: first layer with small raft]

[image: first layer with large raft]
[image: model peeling off of print bed]

Comment: Are you sure the room temperature is not too low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you have done a lot of work to try to get it working.

considering you are having issues on one side of the build plate my thought is that it is a levelling issue or an issue with the plate itself. Try levelling it using the video ["Getting Started: Leveling the Build Plate"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4G6ExEtk70) it's for a different printer but pay attention to the part where he goes over making sure the left and right sides are level and how to check that. I had a problem like yours, and the issue was that as I tightened the screw to keep the build plate in the levelled position I ended up causing it to move. I made the same mistake a few times before realizing that I was messing it up the same way every time because I'm right-handed. after realizing that it was easier to fix.

If the issue is the build plate it's self it may be a matter of it not being flat (unlikely), Or not providing a good bonding surface. if the latter I suggest you do some research and decide for yourself as there are a lot of dividing views on how to fix that issue.

It also looks like you are having issues with the print after the bottom layers. It could be caused but the separation issue but it could be that you just need to increase your exposure time for your non-bottom layers

Comment: It was indeed found that my plate was not level. The manufscturer shipped a new plate, the issues did however not go away. I will try your advice regarding tightening of the screws and such.. If that does not work, I will try different resin (Sirayatech).

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with my Vat Bolts, one being cracked and leveling at a greater tension than the other.  With the compressible feet of my Vat this caused a problem in the FEP.  This was enough to cause failure on one side more than the other.  Cause was verified by switching the left and right knobs, thus shifting the failures to the opposite side of the print.

Just a thought.

Comment: Did you mean "this caused a ***shift*** in the FEP"?